# why the solution can just add or minus the degree directly when calculating the line voltage?

Tags: voltage

There is a three-phase electric power systems which is arranged in star (Y) ,and positvie phase sequence.

Now if the \$\bar V_{ab}=220∠60^∘ \$,then what is the \$\bar V_{bc}\$ and \$\bar V_{ca}\$?

The solution told me

\$\bar V_{bc}=220∠(60^∘-120^∘)=220∠(-60^∘)\$

\$\bar V_{ca}=220∠(60^∘+120^∘)=220∠(180^∘)\$

But i am curious about can we really do that?just calculate the degree part directly?

Because we can see the proof below in lots of books

\$\bar V_{AB}=\bar V_{AO}+\bar V_{BO}=V_p ∠0^∘- V_p ∠120^∘=\sqrt{3}V_p ∠30^∘ \neq  V_p ∠0-120^∘=V_p ∠-120^∘\$

So why the solution can just add or minus the degree directly?or can anyone tell me the original math formula about \$\bar V_{bc}\$ or  \$\bar V_{ca}\$?

Comment: The definition of a three-phase system is that the voltages are *generated* 120° apart so why would you *not* do this?

Comment: @Transistor But if it is right,don't you think the \$\bar V_{AB}=\bar V_{AO}+\bar V_{BO}=V_p ∠0^∘- V_p ∠120^∘\$ should be equal to \$V_p ∠-120^∘\$ ,not \$\sqrt{3}V_p ∠30^∘\$

Comment: What is \$ V_p \$? Have you got a diagram you can insert in your question?